# Generating new css from old css file that consists only needed selectors using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, parsing

I have css file that has over 2000 lines. Is there any way to create mini js function that will parse html, fetch only needed selectors from this .css file and generate new css?

Comment: I believe you could use the CSS tab in Firebug or Chrome Console to get the active style definitions.

Comment: Are we talking about reusable production code, or a quick one time script to make life easier for you?

Comment: @JaredFarrish are you sure that they are only active selectors? I got not exactly but nearly same result

Comment: @gilly3 I want to generate new css, that will consist of only existing selectors

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. Setting [up a test](http://jsfiddle.net/rkZfE/) to check, I see that `.blurg` is emptied out. So you might be able to filter out any definitions that are empty. It's a start, at least. Note, as well, it's going to give you the expanded declarations as well, not shortcuts like `background: yada`.

Comment: @epic_syntax - Yes, I got that much.  The question I'm asking is do you want to do this just once?  Or are you building an application where you will analyze a website's css usage?

Answer (score 2):

Use IE9 (for its more robust `StyleSheet` DOM).  Run this script in your JavaScript console:

```
var used = [], unused = [];
[].forEach.call(document.styleSheets, function (ss) {
    [].forEach.call(ss.cssRules, function (r) {
        if (document.querySelector(r.selectorText)) {
            used.push(r);
        } else {
            unused.push(r);
        }
    });
});
console.log("Selectors that exist in this page: " + used.length);
console.log("Selectors that do not exist in this page: " + unused.length);

used.map(function (rule) {
    return rule.cssText;
}).join("\n");
```

It will print out in the console only the rules that you need for a given page.

Comment: it didn't help, totally destructed page

Comment: this is what I was going for, but you have it better.

Answer (score 0):

Not a js solution but have you checked out [Dust Me](http://www.sitepointstatic.com/dustmeselectors/)?

From the site :

> It extracts all the selectors from all the stylesheets on the page you're viewing, then analyzes that page to see which of those selectors are not used. The data is then stored so that when testing subsequent pages, selectors can be crossed off the list as they're encountered.
>
> You can test pages individually, or spider an entire site, and you'll
>   end up with a profile of which selectors are not used anywhere.

However, it is not available for Firefox 8 :(

[Here](https://github.com/geuis/helium-css) is a javascript solution.  I havent tried this one but Dust Me has done the trick for me in the past.

Comment: Tried both, Dust me doesnt work with current ff, helium css gives wrong results